# Why wouldn't request method execute in my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just started learning nodejs and when I was following Js bootcamp course, this code's "req.on" part wouldn't work for me while it did execute for the instructor, I am even unable to console.log('1') inside req.on

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()`enter code here`

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`
      <div>
        <form method="POST">
          <input placeholder="email" />
          <input placeholder="password" />
          <input placeholder="password confirmation" />
          <button>Sign Up</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    `);
});
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
   
    req.on('data', data => {
        console.log('1')
        const parsed = data.toString('utf8').split('&')
        const formData = {}

        for (let _ of parsed) {
            const [key, value] = _.split('=')
            formData[key] = value
        }
        console.log(formData)
    })

    res.send('Account created!!!');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening')
})
```

Comment: What won't work? How are you sending a query? If you are learning add as much detail because you might not know what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form has no successful controls.

When you submit a form each input will be used to generate a `name=value` pair to include in the submitted data.

None of your input elements have `name` attributes, so no data is submitted.

---

Aside:

- `data` events fire every time a chunk of data arrives. Assuming the **first** chunk of data will contain **all** the data is not a safe assumption.
- Express has [APIs that do this for you](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body) so it isn't a good idea to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working now. I was trying hard to find a mistake in my javascript but it was the html portion which actually was lacking